# Keyboard shortcuts in Alation

Tags: hiveql, alation

Is there a Ctrl+Enter keyboard shortcut in Alation to run a query, or a way to enable it?
On Windows (running Alation Compose in browser mode), Shift+F5 runs the current statement, but unlike Toad or SQL Developer, Ctrl+Enter does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

try using `ctrl+r` or the `F5` key to run your entire query.

You can also find out about more hotkeys in the help menu in the upper right corner.

[hotkey menu location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjdYm.png)

Comment: Thank you! I looked up the hot-keys and yes, there's a hotkey 'Ctrl+Enter' to run a full-query or selection, which is what I want.
But when I hit 'Ctrl+Enter', it pops up this dialog instead of running the query, and I can't figure out how to have 'Ctrl+Enter' run the query (or query selection) instead.